# Understanding bookmarks in docx file

Tags: python, xml, openxml, docx, python-docx

I am trying to extract bookmarks from a Docx file, I wrote a piece of code which is extracting bookmarks in some Docx files, but it couldn't find any bookmarks in some docx files. I am using python-docx

I am basically finding `w:bookmarkStart` tags and going to its parent tag and retrieving all the runs in the paragraph. But some documents neither have `w:bookmarkStart` nor hyperlink tag but the Docx viewers are able to identify the bookmarks.

Here is the [XML](http://dpaste.com/3WQTCTA#wrap) content of paragraph which is a bookmark in docx viewer but doesn't contain any bookmark or hyperlink tags.

**Note:** The code I mentioned is working for Docx files created using Google Docs.

```py
    from docx.oxml.shared import qn
    from docx import Document

    def get_toc(self):
        doc_element = self.document.part._element
        bookmarks_list = doc_element.findall('.//' + qn('w:bookmarkStart'))
        for bookmark in bookmarks_list:
            par = bookmark.getparent()
            runs = par.findall(qn('w:r'))
            for run in runs:
                try:
                    print(' ', run.find(qn('w:t')).text, end=' ')
                except:
                    pass
            print('\n','-'*50)
```

Am I missing something or do I need to find some other tags?

If not, how can I identify bookmarks in such scenarios?

Comment: Where are the other bookmarks located? Are they in headers or footers possibly? Also, I would recommend using the `.xpath()` method over `.findall()`. So that would be something like `bookmarkStarts = doc_element.xpath(".//w:bookmarkStart")`. Also, what is the "Docx viewer" you mention? Is that a google docs thing?

Comment: **Are they in headers or footers possibly?  -** I checked document.xml but could see only one occurrence of the text. Is there any other place where i need to check.
**what is the "Docx viewer" you mention? Is that a google docs thing? -** yes.
No luck after changing findall to xpath.

Comment: My next move would be to load the document in Microsoft Word and see if you see the same thing. I don't believe `.docx` is the native format of Google docs, so they might have some other "bookmark"-ish concept that doesn't export cleanly to the DOCX format.

Comment: yes, you are right. I checked with Libre office and ms word, and couldn't see same as bookmarks. So it might be some google docs specific logic. But, the better part is google docs is creating the hierarchy which is exactly required for the doc.
I think i should write some logic based on styles and bold characteristics

Answer (score 2):

In Open XML documents, a bookmark is defined by a matched pair of one `w:bookmarkStart` and one `w:bookmarkEnd` element, where each one has a `w:id` attribute with the same value.

Here is an example paragraph with a bookmark that just contains the text "second" and not the full text of the paragraph (e.g., "First, second, and third").

```xml
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">First, </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="MyBookmarkName" />
  <w:r>
    <w:t>second</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1" />
  <w:r>
    <w:t>, and third.</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

This means that:

- there is no bookmark without those `w:bookmarkStart` and `w:bookmarkEnd` elements (so the paragraph you linked does not contain a bookmark) and
- retrieving the full text of the `w:p` just because you found a `w:bookmarkStart` element is not correct.

And there are more things to note:

- A bookmark can span multiple paragraphs, leaving out one or more leading runs of the `w:p` containing the `w:bookmarkStart` and one or more trailing runs of the `w:p` containing the `w:bookmarkEnd`.
- Both `w:bookmarkStart` and `w:bookmarkEnd` can even appear outside of `w:p` elements, e.g., as child elements of `w:body`.