# accessing bookmarks using python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I am using the python-docx module to read and edit a .docm file,
The file contains bookmarks, how do I access all the bookmarks already stored using that module, there doesnt seem to be any methods within the doc object.

Comment: It is still an [open issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/109) on the python-docx project.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @D Malan, now in 2021-november it is still an open [issue](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/109) in the python-docx.

Meanwhile we can live with our own implementation.

Please create a file named `docxbookmark.py` in a folder accessible as an import:

```
from docx.document import Document as _innerdoclass
from docx import Document as _innerdocfn
from docx.oxml.shared import qn
from lxml.etree import Element as El

class Document(_innerdoclass):
    def _bookmark_elements(self, recursive=True):
        if recursive:
            startag = qn('w:start')
            bkms = []
            def _bookmark_elements_recursive(parent):
                if parent.tag == startag:
                    bkms.append(parent)
                for el in parent:
                    _bookmark_elements_recursive(el)
            _bookmark_elements_recursive(self._element)
            return bkms
        else:
            return self._element.xpath('//'+qn('w:bookmarkStart'))
    def bookmark_names(self):
        """
        Gets a list of bookmarks
        """
        return [v for bkmkels in self._bookmark_elements() for k,v in bkmkels.items() if k.endswith('}name')]
    def add_bookmark(self, bookmarkname):
        """
        Adds a bookmark with bookmark with name bookmarkname to the end of the file
        """
        el = [el for el in self._element[0] if el.tag.endswith('}p')][-1]
        el.append(El(qn('w:bookmarkStart'),{qn('w:id'):'0',qn('w:name'):bookmarkname}))
        el.append(El(qn('w:bookmarkEnd'),{qn('w:id'):'0'}))
    def __init__(self, innerDocInstance = None):
        super().__init__(Document, None)
        if innerDocInstance is not None and type(innerDocInstance) is _innerdoclass:
            self.__body = innerDocInstance.__body
            self._element = innerDocInstance._element
            self._part = innerDocInstance._part

def DocumentCreate(docx=None):
    """
    Return a |Document| object loaded from *docx*, where *docx* can be
    either a path to a ``.docx`` file (a string) or a file-like object. If
    *docx* is missing or ``None``, the built-in default document "template"
    is loaded.
    """
    return Document(_innerdocfn(docx))
```

Now we can use our facade implementation just like the old one, along with those new `add_bookmark` and `bookmark_names`.

To add a bookmark in a new file, import our implementation and use `add_bookmark` on the document object:

```
from docxbookmark import DocumentCreate as Document

doc = Document()
document.add_paragraph('First Paragraph')
document.add_bookmark('FirstBookmark')
document.add_paragraph('Second Paragraph')
document.save('docwithbookmarks.docx')
```

To see bookmarks in a document, import our implementation and use `bookmark_names` on the document object:

```
from docxbookmark import DocumentCreate as Document

doc = Document('docwithbookmarks.docx')
doc.bookmark_names()
```

The returned list is simplier than other objects, it shows only strings not objects. There is an internal `_bookmark_elements` which will return lxml nodes which are not the same as python-docx objects.

Just a few tests were made, probably not working in many cases. Please tell in the comments if it didn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I won't have time to try it out before the bounty expires, so I just went ahead and awarded it anyway. Just one ask: Is there any way you could edit your answer to link the issue in python-docx?

Comment: Ok, link added and thanks for the bounty

Answer (score 0):

Knowing this is old, the issue is still open on GitHub.
The given Answer by brunoff is really helpful but seemed not to work at all. Even if the bookmarks can be readed, possible bookmarks in the headers and footers of multiple sections would be ignored. It would produce dublicates this way also.

```
from docx.document import Document as _innerdoclass
from docx import Document as _innerdocfn
from docx.oxml.shared import qn
from lxml.etree import Element as El


class Document(_innerdoclass):
    def _bookmark_elements(self, recursive=True):
        if recursive:
            startag = qn('w:bookmarkStart')
            bkms = {}

            def _bookmark_elements_recursive(parent):
                if parent.tag == startag:
                    bookmark_name = parent.attrib.get(qn('w:name'))
                    bookmark_id = str(parent.attrib.get(qn('w:id')))
                    if bookmark_name:
                        bkms[bookmark_id] = {
                            'name': bookmark_name,
                            'current_value': parent.text,
                            'new_value': '',
                        }
                for el in parent:
                    _bookmark_elements_recursive(el)

            for section in self.sections:
                for header in section.header.part.element:
                    _bookmark_elements_recursive(header)

                _bookmark_elements_recursive(self.element)

                for footer in section.footer.part.element:
                    _bookmark_elements_recursive(footer)
            return bkms
        else:
            return self._element.xpath('//' + qn('w:bookmarkStart'))

    def bookmark_names(self):
        """
        Returns a list of bookmarks
        """
        return dict(sorted(self._bookmark_elements().items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))

    def add_bookmark(self, bookmarkname):
        """
        Adds a bookmark with bookmark with name bookmarkname to the end of the file
        """
        el = [el for el in self._element[0] if el.tag.endswith('}p')][-1]
        el.append(El(qn('w:bookmarkStart'), {qn('w:id'): '0', qn('w:name'): bookmarkname}))
        el.append(El(qn('w:bookmarkEnd'), {qn('w:id'): '0'}))

    def __init__(self, innerDocInstance=None):
        super().__init__(Document, None)
        if innerDocInstance is not None and type(innerDocInstance) is _innerdoclass:
            self.__body = innerDocInstance.__body
            self._element = innerDocInstance._element
            self._part = innerDocInstance._part


def DocumentCreate(docx=None):
    """
    Return a |Document| object loaded from *docx*, where *docx* can be
    either a path to a ``.docx`` file (a string) or a file-like object. If
    *docx* is missing or ``None``, the built-in default document "template"
    is loaded.
    """
    return Document(_innerdocfn(docx))
```

I just changed **_bookmark_elements_recursive** so it works with **bookmarkStart** and made sure the sections are taken into the dict **bkms** which a also changed from the list so I handle ID's as Keys and this becomes easier to use.

I didn't want to make the call to prevent dublicates at all.

Thomas Barnekow made a pretty good example of how a docx-file is structured and how XML is used: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59111255/2823842

For Short: when a **bookmarkStart** is found, a **run (w:r)** and a text (w:t) inside of if *could* be provided.