# How to get all bookmarks in the word document using python?

Tags: python, ms-word, docx, bookmarks

I need to extract all bookmarks in my '.docx' ms-word file, however the code I found is not working correctly.

```
from win32com import client
app=client.Dispatch('Word.Application')#Start independent process
app.Visible=True #Whether the setting is visible, if it is false, it will run in the background
word=app.Documents.Open(os.path.abspath('Word document path')) #Open word document
bookmarks=word.BookMarks #Get all bookmarks
```

The site where I found the code: https://www.programmersought.com/article/42847366218/

The return of the bookmark variable is: `<COMObject <unknown>`. I would like all BookMarks to appear in text format so I could file them any way I want.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

*I found answer in another stackoverflow question:*
[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704672/understanding-bookmarks-in-docx-file)

**So function is:**

```
def get_bookmarks(document):
    doc_element = document.part._element
    bookmarks_list = doc_element.findall('.//' + qn('w:bookmarkStart'))
    bookmarks_text = []

    for bookmark in bookmarks_list:
        par = bookmark.getparent()
        runs = par.findall(qn('w:r'))
        for run in runs:
            try:
                bookmarks_text.append(run.find(qn('w:t')).text)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    return bookmarks_text
```

***It's using docx (python module [Install](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/))***

*document is docx.Document('path_example.docx')*

Comment: it might be better to flag the question as duplicate to your linked question above

Comment: I used your answer and managed to solve my problem. Thanks!